# Stub methods in Android widget using Mockito

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

I want to stub some methods in a custom Android Widget to test it. I made a test case:

```
public class FooWidgetTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
    }

    public void testMeasure() {
        final FooWidget widget = spy(new FooWidget(getContext()));
        //doReturn(42).when(widget).getFoo();
        widget.measure(makeMeasureSpec(100, EXACTLY), makeMeasureSpec(80, AT_MOST));
        assertEquals(100, widget.getMeasuredWidth());
        assertEquals(80, widget.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}
```

Here I create a spy using Mockito and call `measure` to test the implementation of `onMeasure`.
When `measure` is called I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.foo.widget.FooWidget.isLayoutModeOptical:()Z from class FooWidget_Proxy
```

The method `isLayoutModeOptical` from `ViewGroup` has package-level visibility therefore Mockito couldn't call it from the proxy object.

Is there any way to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add:

```
    doReturn(true).when(widget).isLayoutModeOptical();
```

Mockito should be able to mock package level methods also :)

Comment: Doesn't work because `isLayoutModeOptical` isn't visible from test method.